# Zip file to memory and read entire archive as bytes python

Tags: python, zip

I'm trying to zip an xml file and then read the archive as bytes. Currently, I'm doing this by saving the zip to disk and reading it back as follows:

```
zipfile.ZipFile('x.zip', mode='w').write('x.xml')
with open('x.zip', "rb") as f:
    bytes = f.read()
```

Yet I don't require the zip file itself so keeping it on disk is a waste. I also need to have the zip archive to have the same name as the file. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[`ZipFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile) first argument can be either path to file or file-like object.

You can pass [in-memory buffer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) like

```
from io import BytesIO
buffer = BytesIO()
zipfile.ZipFile(buffer, mode='w').write('README.md')
buffer.seek(0)
```

And use `buffer` like file opened in `b` mode

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `ZipFile.write()`, call `ZipFile.writestr()`. Unless I am missing something, I think that will do what you want.